# How do I create a parallel spliterator from multiple iterators?

Tags: java, java-8, iterator, java-stream

I have a list of cursor-backed iterators that are returned by a method that executes multiple database queries.

Since each cursor-backed iterator is partitioned as such on the database, I'd like to leverage parallel-stream operations on the resultant stream as well. For this, I'd like to create a spliterator.

```
List<Iterator<Article>> articleIterators = executeQuery();
```

How would I go about creating a spliterator? Assume that the items in each iterator are ordered. It is possible that my thinking is fundamentally flawed.

---

A bit more background: I run multiple Cassandra queries so each query hits a different partition. Each query returns its own lazy paging iterator.

Comment: If I may try to (over)simplify the problem, given that the benefit to processing these data sets in parallel is established, I'd do something that easily achieves exactly that, but simply and reliably (like a correctly sized executor service taking a stream task for each iterator). IMO, trying to run this through a single parallel stream pipeline will take a bit of engineering to come up with a split iterator that would partition collections exactly as desired, and in a deterministic way.

Comment: @ernest_k actually, composed streams (`concat` or `flatMap`) tend to split precisely at their components, which would be these iterators. The bigger problem is that the parallel stream will be configured according to the local number of CPU cores, instead of the number of database partitions.

Comment: @Holger great, that makes an easy-ish answer for the OP's question (unless that's up to the implementation - tl;dr)

Comment: @ernest_k I’d prefer your approach of telling about the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You may could have a try with `Stream` provided in [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
List<Stream<Integer>> iters = IntStream.range(1, 32).mapToObj(it -> Stream.repeat(1, it).peek(Fn.sleep(3))).toList();

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Stream.concat(iters).sumInt(Integer::intValue);
System.out.println("Took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)); // print out: Took: 1535

iters = IntStream.range(1, 32).mapToObj(it -> Stream.repeat(1, it).peek(Fn.sleep(3))).toList();

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Stream.parallelConcat(iters).sumInt(Integer::intValue);
System.out.println("Took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)); // print out: Took: 251
```

Disclaimer：I'm the developer of [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common).